# Dealing with Node File Objects - Uploading file to Amazon S3 throws [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, axios, formidable

I've a very bare setup using: Axios > Express > S3 (v3:`@aws-sdk/client-s3`).

- A file is added on the frontend via `<input>`
- A `FormData` object is appended and Axios calls an endpoint
- Express then calls the S3 upload function.

When the file gets to the Node-side it's automatically converted to a Node `File Object` format (which I don't know what do with). The `@aws-sdk` attempts to convert it to a Buffer, which throws the error from `buffer.js:333`.

The complete error thrown (minus the call stack) is:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first
> argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer,
> or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of File

Here are the pertantint bits of script.

```
// Frontend.js
const sendImage = () => {
  const image = document.querySelector('#photoupload');
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('image', image.files[0]);
  axios.post('http://192.168.1.152:3200/addImage', formData, {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    },
  });
};
```

```
// express-server.js
app.use(cors());
app.use(formidable())
app.post('/addImage', (req, res) => {
  const file = req.files;
  uploadOneToBucket('my_s3_bucket', file);
});
```

```
// s3_uploadMethod.js
const uploadOneToBucket = (bucketName, file) => {
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    Body: file.image,
    Key: file.image.name,
  };
  const s3Upload = s3.send(new PutObjectCommand(params));
  // handle Promises
};
```

I'm not quite sure how to go about solving this problem. One question, how should I deal with the Node File Object so the S3 `PutObjectCommand` can use it?
A further question is, what is the best practice for file uploading, I've seen people talk about converting to a base64 Buffer, while others say to stream it.
I appreciate y'alls help!

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to convert the file on the frontend to `base64`, putting it inside of a `FormData` Object and convert it back on the server-side. The downside to this method is the `base64` string is about 30% bigger than the original file. I assume there's a better solution out there.

The altered code uses the built-in [FileReader Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

```
 // Frontend.js 
 const sendImage = () => {
    const image = document.querySelector('#photoupload').files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    const formData = new FormData();
    reader.addEventListener('loadend', () => {
      formData.append('image', image.name + reader.result);
      axios.post('http://192.168.1.152:3200/addImage', formData, {
        headers: {
          'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      });
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(image);
  };
```

```
// server.js
app.use(cors());
app.use(formidable());
app.post('/addImage', (req, res) => {
  const file = req.fields;
  uploadOneToBucket('my_s3_bucket', file.image);
});
```

```
// s3_uploadMethod.js
const uploadOneToBucket = (bucketName, file) => {
  const data = file.split(',');
  const decodedBuffer = Buffer.from(data[1], 'base64');
  const filename = (data[0].split('data')[0]);

  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    ACL: 'public-read',
    Body: decodedBuffer,
    Key: filename,
  };
  // ...
```